# Why the Unnecessary 'else' after 'return' (no-else-return) error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, ecmascript-6, eslint

I always use the else statement. And the data from the Data.js file. Is there something I might have overlooked?

```
import data from './Data'

function List(props){
  const filteredData = data.filter((el) => {
    if (props.input === '') {
      return el
    } else {
      return el.text.tiLowerCase().includes(props.input)
    }
  })
```

Comment: If the `if` condition is true, the function will return, so the `else` is superfluous. It's kind-of a matter of opinion, but personally I really dislike an `else` after a `return` like that, because it obscures what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's [just what the rule requires](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-else-return).

> Disallows return before else.
>
> If an if block contains a return statement, the else block becomes unnecessary. Its contents can be placed outside of the block.

If you think this rule is worth following, use instead (with correct spelling)

```
const filteredData = data.filter((el) => {
    if (props.input === '') {
        return el
    }
    return el.text.toLowerCase().includes(props.input)
})
```

or even better

```
const filteredData = data.filter((el) => {
    return props.input === ''
        ? el
        : el.text.toLowerCase().includes(props.input)
})
```

If `el` will alwys be truthy, then it would make more sense to return `true` instead.

```
const filteredData = data.filter((el) => {
    return props.input === ''
        ? true
        : el.text.toLowerCase().includes(props.input)
})
```

which allows for the simplification to

```
const filteredData = data.filter((el) => {
    return props.input === '' || !el.text.toLowerCase().includes(props.input)
})
```